# How can I renew my non-current Indian CPL?

Tags: dgca-india-regulations

I have not renewed my Indian CPL since 2001 and would like to renew it. what is the procedure as the CAR says nothing about renewing licence below 5700 kgs category.
Since there is no rule what can be done. I am flying regularly on my FAA licence.

Answer (score 1):

[image: CPL competency]

This is for CAA , each country might have a different rule but in general this is the rule . If you haven't flown in India since 2001 then your license has been expired. So I assume that if you have any other license valid , you have to go to Indian civil aviation with your current  log book and they will request a confirmation from the country that you have got your license from to be sure that your license is still valid in that country.Then you have to do the conversion requirements which generally are 4 exams (for most countries are Law,HP,Nav, Met) and then you also have to go to any ATO in India and you must undergo sufficient ground and flight training for the same category aircraft that you have your other license on , and then do a oral exam and flight test .

If you haven't flown in the last 10 years , you have to do all CPL exams again .
Good luck.